# How does a teleprinter work?

Tags: communication

How in detail does a teleprinter system work? I am aware that many teleprinter used the Baudot code to relate alpha-numeric symbols to a sequence of 5 bits. What is the mechanical means by which a letter inputted in the type-writter machine on the sending end results in a signal being interuptted according in the corresponding Baudot sequence. And what is the means by which such a signal can be recieved by a machine and then converted to the corresponding letter (which is then printed on a tape, I believe). Also can somone please clarify how exactly start and stop bits are used to signal transitions between letters/words?

Comment: For future reference, Joshua.  Radically rewriting a question like that is bad form.  If somebody were in the process of writing an answer to the original version (about the 1846 printing telegraph), you would have pulled the rug from under them.

Answer (score 2):

The original teletypes were electromechanical devices. Fairly simple electrically, but moderately complex mechanically.

To transmit, each key on the keyboard changes the position of five levers or bars in a particular pattern (32 combinations). These bars change the position of five electrical contacts, which are then "scanned" by a set of cams on a rotating shaft, in order to create a pattern of open/closed circuit conditions on the electrical interface, which is a "current loop". The first bit is always an "open", and this functions as the "start" bit. The five data bits follow this in sequence.

The on/off current pulses are fed to an electromagnet on the receiving side, which operates a lever. In the "idle" state, the lever holds a rotating shaft still against the force from a motor/clutch combination. When the start bit comes through, it releases the shaft, which makes one rotation at the same speed as the one in the transmitter. During this rotation, a set of cams and linkages is used to "test" the position of the electromagnet lever during each of the data bits, and a bar or lever for each bit is set accordingly. At the end of the cycle, the combined position of the five bars enables just one of the typewriter print bars to be activated and print on the paper.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dave's excellent answer, I thought an explanation of how these devices got by on only 32 codes would be useful. Since 32 (5 bits) is not enough to encode all combinations of letters, numbers and punctuation, two codes of the 32 (LTRS and FIGS) are used to switch back and forth between two sets of characters.   So there are really 30 codes available for characters in each set.

Once a LTRS or FIGS code is sent, the device is assumed to stay in that mode until switched back; i.e. it is like the Caps Lock function on a modern keyboard. So in terms of Dave's answer, sending the LTRS or FIGS code would lock some lever in position for the desired character set.

The "letters" group includes:

```
null space A-Z CR LF FIGS
```

where null means a blank character is sent (if punched on tape, it would mean no holes); CR is a carriage return, LF is a line feed, and FIGS is the code to shift to the "figures" characters.

Note that only uppercase alphabetic characters can be sent.

The "figures" group includes:

```
null space 0-9, -, bell, WRU? ! & # ' ( ) " / : ; ? . , CR LF LTRS
```

where WRU? (who are you?) was used to trigger an answerback mechanism; and LTRS is the code to switch back to the letters character set.

Also note that the null, space, CR and LF are present in both character groups, so they are always available.

Here is a Baudot keyboard showing the two FIGS and LTRS keys circled in red.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can *always* send both `LTRS` and `FIGS` in either mode.

Comment: @DaveTweed good point, if the operator walks away and comes back later, they don't have to remember what mode they were last in.

Comment: Would it not be possible to increase the speed of communication by using a seperate wire to transmit each of the 5 bits. That would remove the need for the bits to be sent seperatley (at some time interval determined by the rotation of the shaft) although I this might create problems if a second set of 5 bits is sent immediatley after the first set, before the first set is "processed" by the recieving side. This can be solved by adding a 6th wire which will transmit start bits immediatley after a letter is typed using a rotating shaft with 2 cams,one for the first 5 wires,one for the 6th wire.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou The cost would be prohibitive.  These devices were used to send messages over hundreds of miles of wire.  Speed of communication was increased instead by increasing the number of bits that could be sent per second (baud).  Teletypes started out at 45.5 baud, and increased to 50, 75, 100, 150 and then 300 baud.  When electronic modems came into use, speeds continued to increase, up to a maximum of 57,600 baud for regular telephone lines -- over 1200 times the original speed.

Comment: Was there any advantage over having a NUL in addition to LTRS and FIGS, as opposed to using either LTRS or FIGS as a padding character as appropriate?

Comment: @supercat The main advantage is the NUL characters could be used to "punch" blank paper tape.  Also, sometimes the teletype motor would be turned off (either manually or remotely via a explicit code, such as FIGS H); a series of perhaps a dozen NUL characters could be used to turn the motor back on and allow it to stabilize without missing any real characters since the timing was not critical.  An initial  LTRS or FIGS character might get garbled.